# Ext.EventManager is deprecated in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

In ExtJS 5 I'm getting console warning saying

> [W] Ext.EventManager is deprecated. Use Ext.dom.Element#addListener to
>   attach an event listener.

I am using code statement bellow,

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
    //code here
});
```

I understand that `Ext.EventManager` is deprecated but how should I replace my code statement to work it in extjs 5 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getWin()` method and append event handler using `on`.

```
Ext.getWin().on('beforeunload',function(){ 
   //code here
});
```

Other possible option would be to use pure JavaScript.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    //Code here
};
```

Comment: BTW. Replacement for `Ext.EventManager.on(document, 'keydown', ...` is `Ext.getDoc().on('keydown', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
Ext.getWin().[m]on('beforeunload', function() {
    //code here
});
```

You could've find that yourself in the [manual](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.EventManager). Form the docs:

> Registers event handlers on DOM elements.
>
> This class is deprecated. Please use the Ext.dom.Element api to attach
>   listeners to DOM Elements. For example:

```
var element = Ext.get('myId');

element.on('click', function(e) {
    // event handling logic here
});
```

Comment: `window.on('beforeunload', function() {}` throwing console error `Uncaught TypeError: window.on is not a function`

Comment: `window` is the native DOM element; `Ext.getWin()` returns the ExtJS wrapper.

Comment: Thx, Robert. Edited my answer to be more precise :)